# Time Sheet Record Check for Date Order

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have the employees clock in records here.
[image]

What I'm trying to do is, I want to filter the names of these records in "Check" Tab against the date in order.

[image]

If the employee is present on the particular day (A Column), I wan to pull the record of that particular employee in the B1 and populate it against the date in A column, If he is absent on that day, It has to be marked as Absent.

I tried doing this in many ways with array formula, Query, and V Look up but ended with errors. can you help me with this?

This is my sample working sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bahNEJIweyuvmocYbSR87xL5Nc_IA_HP3qdO7tCKU6w/edit#gid=1124870615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=arrayformula(if(A3:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A3:A&B1,{INT(Records!B:B)&Records!A:A,Records!A:D},{3,4,5},false),),))`

Taking into account of future dates and 'ABSENT':

`=arrayformula(if(A3:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A3:A&B1,{INT(Records!B:B)&Records!A:A,Records!A:D},{2,3,4,5},false),IF(A3:A<=TODAY(),"ABSENT","-")),))`

Breakdown:

`VLOOKUP` takes the date from Col `A` and the name from `B1` and then refers to the first `{}`, to compare against `{INT(Records!B:B)&Records!A:A` which is the whole day without the time using `INT` around the date/time, and the person name.

Where there is an exact match, `{2,3,4,5}` brings back columns 2,3,4,5 from the second array `{}`.

If there is an error matching `IFERROR`, then checks `IF(A3:A<=TODAY(),"ABSENT","-")`. If the day is today or before, it puts `"ABSENT"`, otherwise `"-"`.

`if(A3:A<>""`... at the start only does the `VLOOKUP` whilst the value in column A is not blank, otherwise `,)` does nothing (the space between `,` and `)`).

`ARRAYFORMULA` works down the sheet.

Comment: Can you help me to add the ABSENT there is no record on the date order?

Comment: Thank you for the formula, Now I can play around with it and learn. :)

Comment: Notes added :-)